# Passing environment variables from Docker to Nginx configuration files not working

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am really stumped and can use help figuring out why my environment variables aren't transferring from Docker to nginx config files.

I have a `docker-compose.yml`

```
nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: proxier
    volumes:
      - ./conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./conf/server.nginx.conf.tpl:/etc/nginx/server.nginx.conf.tpl
      - ./build/web:/srv/static:ro
      - ./docker/proxier:/tmp/docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - HOST_EXTERNAL_IP=localhost
      - DEVSERVER_PORT=8000
      - DEVSERVICE_PORT=5000
    command: /bin/bash -c "env && envsubst '$$HOST_EXTERNAL_IP $$DEVSERVER_PORT $$DEVSERVICE_PORT' < /etc/nginx/server.nginx.conf.tpl > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

I have an `nginx.conf` file

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /dev/stdout warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;


http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  client_max_body_size 100g;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /dev/stdout  main;

  sendfile        off;
  tcp_nopush     on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  gzip on;

  server_tokens off;

  upstream app {
    server myapp:8000 fail_timeout=0;
  }
  include /etc/nginx/server.nginx.conf.tpl;
}
```

I have a `server.nginx.conf.tpl` file

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  server_name localhost;

  index index.html;

  location ^~ /services/ {
      proxy_pass       https://myurl.com;
      proxy_set_header USER_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
      proxy_set_header Host      $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }

  location / {
      proxy_http_version  1.1;
      proxy_set_header    Connection "keep-alive";
      proxy_pass       http://${HOST_EXTERNAL_IP}:${DEVSERVER_PORT}; # Won't read environment variables here
  }
 }
```

When I run this however, I get the error

`nginx: [emerg] unknown "host_external_ip" variable` I am using `envsubst` correctly to pass the environment variable from docker per the [docs](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration)

Comment: Your `include` directive at the end of the main `nginx.conf` is including the unrendered `...tpl` file; it should include the rendered `default.conf` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do not copy nginx.conf directly. Instead create a shell file to generate the nginx file e.g.

```
echo 'you nginx conf goes here with $envVariable' > location/to/conf/folder/nginx.conf
```

and run that file inside the container. So when that shell file will run. It will replace the environment variables that you set with it's actual value in the nginx.conf.
Do not forget to skip $ of nginx variables.

Comment: Thank you, there is full info of it https://www.baeldung.com/linux/nginx-config-environment-variables